# Upgrade Visual Studio from 2008R2 to 2013

Tags: visual-studio

We are currently using Visual Studio 2008 R2, but are trying to seek approval to upgrade to the 2013 version. Would anyone be able to point out a few of the key enhancements that would be available in the new version? This is looking from a reporting perspective, so enhancements to things like graphs & tables are especially of interest.

Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Kind Regards
Dan